# How can I bypass an index error or have the script run again?

Tags: macos, applescript, index-error

I am encountering an index error that appears when the app in use has an overlay or notification appear. To provide a better description, the app will occasionally show an alert if something needs to be acknowledged or dismissed. When that happens, the script is unable to return the value from the designated location in the GUI, and returns the following error message: "Can’t get group 4 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of process "App I'm Using". Invalid index.System Events got an error: Can’t get group 4 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of process "App I'm Using". Invalid index. (-1719)"

The behavior is expected, but I would like to adjust the script to where it will either delay trying again for 30 seconds or so, or just not display said error at all.

I've been toying around with using an 'on error' statement, but I can't get it to take with the 'tell' statement that it's referring to, for example:

```
    on error error_message number error_number
        if error_number = -1719 then
            wait 30
        end if
```

I'm unsure of how I can use the 'on error' function with the section of the script below, but if I can make it try again in 30 - 45 seconds without displaying an error, it would be perfect.

```
on idle
    -- Update the status item's text here.
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process appName) then
            display alert "Application " & appName & " is not running" as warning giving up after 6
            quit me
        end if
        tell process appName
            tell first window's first toolbar's fourth group's first group's first menu button
                set activityState to first item of (value as list) as text
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end idle
```

I believe the error is encountered when the script reaches "tell window's first toolbar's fourth group's..." before it is supposed to "set activityState to first item...".

I have used the 'on error' function with 'try' statements successfully, but I'm having issues moving forward with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try this approach which will remain in the repeat loop until  `first window's first toolbar's fourth group's first group's first menu button` becomes available.

```
on idle
    -- Update the status item's text here.
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process appName) then
            display alert "Application " & appName & " is not running" as warning giving up after 6
            quit me
        end if
        tell process appName
            repeat until exists of first window's first toolbar's fourth group's first group's first menu button
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            tell first window's first toolbar's fourth group's first group's first menu button
                set activityState to first item of (value as list) as text
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end idle
```

Comment: This was the ticket, thank you! It doesn't generate an error, and immediately updates once the toolbar is up front and visible again.

Comment: @wch1zpink - rather than using a repeat/delay loop, you should use the idle handler to advantage. Check it it exists, and return .2 if it doesn't.  Idling is much more processor efficient than loop-delays.

Comment: @TedWrigley You do make a good point.  We also could have just used a `delay 1` command before the `tell first window's ...  menu button`  to allow it time to become available.  For purposes of this example it seemed as if we only needed to buy an extra few fractions of a second. This being the case, processor efficiency really would not have much of an impact.  In addition, I think my answer provides a good example for others who may try to use elements of this code, who may not be using an idle handler, to incorporate into their own scripts. + 1 on your comment though.

Comment: @wch1zpink  Nice answer!  It's great you formulated a solution that _doesn't_ utilise unnecessary `try` blocks; it demonstrates a thoughtful approach to a script. This deserves a +1, as it also illustrates good, robust techniques other users will benefit from copying. I also +1'd Ted's comment above, because he's right. But then I +1'd your response to him, because you're also right. Anyway, good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t split statements (such as **if** or **tell**).  The **try** statement needs to wrap around the complete statement(s) you want it to work with, for example, the statement telling the app process:

```
on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process appName) then
            ---
        end if
        try
            tell process appName
                ---
            end tell
        on error errmess number errnum
            return 30 -- try the idle handler again in 30 seconds
        end try
    end tell
end idle
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` keyword to check if an element is present before trying to access it. `exists` won't through an error if the element isn't there, and will let you skip over the problematic lines:

```
on idle
    -- Update the status item's text here.
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process appName) then
            display alert "Application " & appName & " is not running" as warning giving up after 6
            quit me
        end if
        tell process appName
            -- assuming the window and toolbar are always going to be there
            try
                tell first window's first toolbar
                    -- check to see if the UI element exists
                    if exists fourth group's first group's first menu button then
                        -- only get the activity state if it does
                        tell fourth group's first group's first menu button
                            set activityState to first item of (value as list) as text
                        end tell
                    end if
                end tell
            on error errstr
                (*
                  this code is in an 'idle' handler, so on any error we
                  just return 30 to idle for another 30 seconds and try again.
                 *)
                return 30
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end idle
```

Comment: thanks again for your help! I'm running into the same issue, but a different error message when I use the `exists` keyword. When it is unable to see the toolbar (in the case of a notification / alert appearing), I get: "The variable activityState is not defined. (-2753)". Do I need to move that variable further up in the script perhaps?

Comment: @rackinfrackin - I was trying to target a specific error, but since you seem to have unpredictable errors, I'm going to rewrite the code above so that it just idles for another 30 seconds if it catches any error at all. Note that this won't give you any notification that an error occurred; it's all silent in the background